# Powershell setting variables in foreach-object by getting contents of a batchfile

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach-object

Good day,

Could someone help me with setting some variables after filtering some records from a batchfile in powershell please?

My Batch file (config.bat) looks like this :

```
---------
set FILENAME=OIMSX4455
set USR=AJ34
set DOCTYPE=WORD
set YEAR=2019
---------
```

My Powershell code resembles the below although I'm unsure how to set the variables ie (getting the values "WORD" and "AJ34" into $doc and $user

---

```
$vars = "c:\temp\config.bat"
get-content $vars | select-string -pattern ("set DOCTYPE=","set USR=") 
foreach-object {
$doc=<should equal WORD>
$user=<should equal AJ34>
}
```

---

As my config file changes and has several values, I'm only interested in the  values what comes after = sign for set DOCTYPE= & set USR=  i.e WORD and AJ34  in this example

On another day the config values will change which is why i need to read them again into my powershell variables.  Apologies in advance for any mistakes etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I think is by using regex on a line-by-line comparison with `switch`:

```
$user, $doc = $null
switch -Regex -File 'c:\temp\config.bat' {
    '^set USR\s*=\s*(.*)'     { $user = $matches[1] }
    '^set DOCTYPE\s*=\s*(.*)' { $doc = $matches[1] }
}

Write-Host "user: $user`tdoc: $doc"
```

Result:

```
user: AJ34  doc: WORD
```